# I wrote a probability question I can't solve

Tags: probability, combinations

$\newcommand{\nCk}[2]{{}^{#1}C_{#2}}$
I wrote this question to prep my students for their midterm, and I realized when I sat down to solve it that I can't figure out the right way to think about it.

A costume shop has $7$ costumes available to rent, $4$ of each. You and $9$ friends go to the costume shop independently and each pick a costume. What is the probability you arrive at the party and there are exactly $5$ distinct costumes? (You are the only 10 guests)

I know from simulation that the solution should be something like $0.232402$, perhaps it is $\nCk{7}{5}\cdot 48\cdot\frac{\nCk{15}{5}}{\nCk{28}{10}}$. I can justify the $\nCk{7}{5}$ and the $\nCk{15}{5}$ in the numerator, but not the $48$. $\nCk{7}{5}$ because of the $7$ costumes $5$ are chosen. We need to ensure that $1$ of each are worn by $5$ guests, but the other $5$ are free to choose from the $15$ (hence $\nCk{15}{5}$). But I'm sure I'm thinking about this not quite right. I'd love any explanations. Thanks!

Comment: Ask any of your students if they figured it out

Comment: My attempt got to a number almost double the simulation, posting it anyways in case it helps give you a direction.

Comment: How many attend to the party, suppose only ten who bought costumes. It's not clear in your question.

Answer (score 6):

Begin by computing the quantities
$$
    x_5 = \binom 75 \binom{20}{10}, \; x_4 = \binom 74 \binom{16}{10}, \; x_3 = \binom 73 \binom{12}{10}.
$$
These are a naive way to try to compute the number of ways to have exactly $5$, $4$, or $3$ costumes present at the party (fewer is impossible). In each case, we choose which costumes they are, then choose which $10$ "instances" of those costumes were actually bought. (This will be out of a total of $\binom{28}{10}$ possibilities, since there are $28$ "instances" of costumes at the store.)

However, there's some complicated overcounting going on. If only $4$ costumes are present, $x_5$ counts that outcome $3$ times: once for each set of $5$ costumes containing those $4$. If only $3$ costumes are preset, $x_5$ counts that outcome $6$ times: once for each set of $5$ costumes containing those $3$. Similarly, if only $3$ costumes are present, $x_4$ counts that outcome $4$ times.

By this reasoning, we have
$$
    \begin{cases}
       x_5 = y_5 + 3 y_4 + 6 y_3 \\
       x_4 = \phantom{y_5 + 1}y_4 + 4 y_3 \\
       x_3 = \phantom{y_5 + 0y_4 + 1}y_3
    \end{cases}
$$
where $y_5, y_4, y_3$ are the actual number of ways to have exactly $5$, exactly $4$, and exactly $3$ costumes at the party.

Solving for $y_5$, we get $y_5 = x_5 - 3x_4 + 6x_3$. Dividing this by $\binom{28}{10}$, we get our final probability of
$$
    \frac{\binom 75 \binom{20}{10} - 3 \binom 74 \binom{16}{10} + 6  \binom 73 \binom{12}{10}}{\binom{28}{10}} = \frac{6608}{28405} \approx 0.232635.
$$

---

We can confirm this result by brute-forcing it in Mathematica.

```
costumes = Join[Range[7], Range[7], Range[7], Range[7]];
outcomes = Subsets[costumes, {10}];
good = Select[outcomes, Length@DeleteDuplicates[#] == 5 &];
Length[good]/Length[outcomes]
```

The output of this code (which just finds all possible ways to buy $10$ costumes, and then counts the ones in which exactly $5$ distinct costumes appear) is, again, $\frac{6608}{28405}$.

Comment: Почему меньше 3 костюмов невозможно?

Comment: You have four copies of each costume and ten people, so the minimum number of different costumes used is four pirates-four skeletons-two draculas etc.

Comment: Thank you, I love the final answer, I just wish I understood the intuition behind the 3 and 6 in the final fraction besides them being the solution from the system of equations.

Answer (score 2):

You can count cases, assigning unidentified people to the costumes... In total there are 7*4 = 28 costumes. Represent them as in the following table (each box of the table corresponds to a costume).

| costume type | exemplar 1 | exemplar 2 | exemplar 3 | exemplar 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |

Represent the event that a costume is rented by somebody by putting an asterisk in its box. For example the 10 people could be renting the following costumes.

| costume type | exemplar 1 | exemplar 2 | exemplar 3 | exemplar 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | * |  | * |  |
| 2 |  | * |  |  |
| 3 | * |  |  | * |
| 4 |  | * | * |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |
| 7 | * |  | * | * |

Since each costume has the same probability of being rented, each distribution of 10 asterisks inside of the 28 boxes has the same probability. There is a total of $\binom{28}{10}$.

possible ways to put the 10 asterisk in the 28 boxes. You are interested in all cases where the 10 asterisks fall in exactly 5 lines. Let's count them.

There are $\binom{7}{5}$ different ways to pick the $5$ lines out of the $7$. Once the $5$ lines have been picked, we want to count how many distributions of 10 asterisks within the $20 = 5\cdot 4$ cases of the $5$ lines satisfy our requirements, i.e. have at least an asterisk each line. That is

(nr. all distributions of $10$ asterisks in the $5$ lines) - (nr. distributions of $10$ asterisks in only $4$ out of the $5$ lines) + (nr. distributions of $10$ asterisks in only $3$ out of the $5$ lines)

which evaluates to:

$$\dbinom{20}{10} - \dbinom{5}{1} 
\cdot \dbinom{16}{10} + \dbinom{5}{2} \cdot \dbinom{12}{10}$$

So the probability (favorable cases divided by total cases) is:

$$\dfrac{ \left( \binom{20}{10} - \binom{5}{1} \cdot \binom{16}{10} + \binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{12}{10} \right) }{\binom{28}{10}} = 0.23263509945432142228480901...$$

With Bin(x,y) of course I mean the binomial coefficient. Sorry for the bad formatting, it's the first time I write here!

Comment: Good job on your first answer! I think it's even a bit cleaner than my approach. If you want to learn how to typeset expressions like the binomial coefficients, the best way to learn is to right-click on the math in someone else's answer and select "Show Math As... > TeX Commands". This code is put between dollar signs `$...$` for a formula that's part of a bigger paragraph, and double dollar signs `$$...$$` for an equation meant to go on its own line.

Comment: This is very excellent. I think the main thing I was not realizing is that ${20 \choose 10}$ is the number of ways to select at most 5 types of costumes, and the inclusion/exclusion aspect is much more clear now. Thank you!

Comment: Ah thanks a lot guys! I didn't realize you could write as in latex :) ... it was also very much fun to think about this problem! have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:  I worked this out as I typed it in to see how it would come up.  My final answer is almost double the simulation, so this is not intended as an answer.  However, hopefully it will spark ideas for how to correct it.

$7C5$ ways of picking the 5 costumes we are using. We are effectively cho0sing partitions of 10 of exactly length 5 where no number greater than 4 can be used.. Going systematically from the highest possible value downward, we could have
$$4 3 1 1 1 :  5C1\cdot 4C1=20$$
$$4 2 2 1 1 :  5C1 \cdot 4 C 2=30$$
$$3 3 2 1 1:  5C2 \cdot 3C1=30$$
$$3 2 2 2 1: 5C1 \cdot 4C3=20$$
$$2 2 2 2 2:   1$$

So that gets us
$$20+30+30+20+1=101$$
partitions times the $7C5=21$, giving us
$$21\cdot 101=2121$$

This would have to be divided by all the ways of partitioning 10 into 3,4,5,6,7 shirt types.

3 shirts: first $7C3=35$ ways of picking which shirts we are using

$$4 4 2: 3C2=3$$
$$4 3 3:  3C1=3$$
so we get $6\cdot 35=210$ here
4 shirts;  First $7C4=35$ ways of the shirt types.  Partitions of length 4:
$$4 4 1 1:  4C2=6$$
$$4 3 2 1 : 4!=24$$
$$3 3 3 1: 4C3=4$$
$$3 3 2 2 : 4C2=6$$
so that's a total of $$(6+24+4+6)\cdot 35=1400$$  here

5 shirts, done above,  $2121$ total
6 shirts:   $7C6=7$ choices of shirts
$$4 2 1 1 1 1 :6C1 \cdot 5C1=30 $$
$$3 3 1 1 1 1:  6C2=15$$
$$3 2 2 1 1 1: 6C1\cdot 5C2=60$$
$$2 2 2 2 1 1: 6C4=15$$
Giving a total of
$$(7+30+15+60+15)\cdot 7=889$$

Finally,  using all 7 shirts:
$$4 1 1 1 1 1 1 : 7C1=7$$
$$3 2 1 1 1 1 1:  7C1\cdot 6C1=42$$
$$2 2 2 1 1 1 1:  7C3=35$$
For a total of $$7+42+35=84$$

So our total pool is $$210+1400+2121+889+84=4704$$

This ended up with $$\frac {2121} {4704} $$, or roughly .446,  almost double the simulation.  I may have made basic arithmatic or logic errors, I'm tired!  Leaving this up long enough until either a better solution is around or it sparks ideas for someone to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to think of this in terms of cards. Suppose I have a partial deck of cards with all 4 aces, all 4 twos, and so on, up until all 4 sevens. I shuffle these 28 cards and then look at the top 10. What is the probability that exactly 5 ranks are presents among these 10 cards.

The denominator is $\binom{28}{10}$. For the numerator, we must first choose the 5 ranks that will be present, giving a factor of $\binom{7}{5}$. Once these are chosen, we must choose the partition of 10, as Alan noted, that these cards will form. From Alan's answer, they are

43111, 42211, 33211, 32221, 22222

We first count the number of ways of selecting cards according to the first partition. We must choose the rank that will have 4 cards, the rank that will have 3, and the three ranks that will have 1. There are
$$
\binom{5}{1,1,3} = \frac{5!}{1!1!3!} = 20
$$
ways to do that. Once that selection is made, we must actually choose the cards. There are
$$
\binom{4}{4}\binom{4}{3}\binom{4}{1}^3
$$
ways to do that. Continuing with this reasoning for the other four partitions, our final answer will be
$$
\frac{\binom{7}{5}}{\binom{28}{10}}\left(
\binom{5}{1,1,3}\binom{4}{4}\binom{4}{3}\binom{4}{1}^3
+ \binom{5}{1,2,2}\binom{4}{4}\binom{4}{2}^2\binom{4}{1}^2
+ \binom{5}{2,1,2}\binom{4}{3}^2\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{1}^2
+ \binom{5}{1,3,1}\binom{4}{3}\binom{4}{2}^3\binom{4}{1}
+ \binom{5}{5}\binom{4}{2}^5
\right).
$$
If my calculations are correct, this should be
$$
\frac{6608}{28405} \approx 0.232635.
$$